# Selecting from 2 Radio buttons when 1 button has no id - Webdriver

Tags: selenium, radio-button, click

I am trying to write a script in web driver and part of the page that I am testing has 2 radio buttons where the person has to agree that something is correct.

By default the no button is selected and the user has to select the yes radio button to continue.

I have read a number of solutions for things similar and I've tried numerous different things but still can't get Selenium to select the yes radio button. It is a Yes/No question. The No field is already pre-populated but I need it to select Yes.

As you can see below there is a small amount of code for this part of the form.

```
<pre>

<form action="">
                <input id="selfCert" name="selfCert" value="no" checked="checked" type="radio">No
                <input name="selfCert" value="yes" type="radio">Yes
            </form>

 </pre>
```

I have tried to use the xpath and the css but the test just terminates.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: Can you ensure that the _HTML_ visible in your question is exactly the same as you observe in your system?

Comment: Based on your shown code segment, both elements do NOT have the same id.  In fact, only the "No" button has an id.

Comment: Yes your right because that code is exactly what it shows. Do you know if there is a way to select the yes option if there is no id?

Answer (score 0):

Can u use xpath to select the Yes radio button?
As both input fields share the same name="selfCert" I think u need to use xpath then.

I have an example in C# for Selenium, if you're using a different language you will need to modify it.

```
YesRadioButton = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form/input[2]"));
YesRadioButton.Click();
```

Comment: I'm using Java but I will give it a go later today.Thanks

Comment: It still won't work. But now I'm wondering whether it has something to do with what happens just prior to me asking it to select the radio button. The task prior to that is a lookup where the system goes away and finds and returns some details to the person. This can take a couple of seconds and it is trying to move to click the radio button before the information has been returned and then then it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the issue now using a wait command until webdriver can see the button

WebElement element = driver1.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/div/form/input[2]"));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver1, 20);

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    element.click();`